# QTreeWdiget adding child element at specific location

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I am trying to build a tree in a way that I can insert the element where I want. This is my tree in its initial stage:

```
+Project
+--Version 1.0
+--Version 2.0
```

Now, let's suppose I made a Version 1.1 and I would like to add it at the location beetween `Version 1.0` and `Version 2.0`. Like:

```
+Project
+--Version 1.0
+--Version 1.1
+--Version 2.0
```

I have tried to add it using insertChild ( http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtreewidgetitem.html#insertChild ) but the item does not get created in the tree. This is the code:

```
void VersionGuiElements::createGuiElements(QTreeWidgetItem* projectItem, int idxAfter)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem* versionItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(0, QStringList(QString("Version ") + m_version->getVersionText())) ;

    if(idxAfter == -1)
    {
        projectItem->addChild(versionItem);
    }
    else
    {
        projectItem->insertChild(idxAfter, versionItem);
    }
}
```

but nothing gets inserted in the tree... any idea what am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

You should point out the parent of tree node when you create it:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* versionItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(projectItem, QStringList(QString("Version ") + m_version->getVersionText())) ;
```

Then:

```
if(idxAfter == -1)
{
    projectItem->addChild(versionItem);
}
else
{
    projectItem->insertChild(idxAfter, versionItem);
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, still the same result. The item is not being added to the tree :(

Comment: Strangely not, although it should.

Comment: Any one have solution for this ??